# Writing a Python Music Streamer

Tags: python, http, streaming, mp3, shoutcast

I would like to implement a server in Python that streams music in MP3 format over HTTP.  I would like it to broadcast the music such that a client can connect to the stream and start listening to whatever is currently playing, much like a radio station.

Previously, I've implemented my own HTTP server in Python using SocketServer.TCPServer (yes I know BaseHTTPServer exists, just wanted to write a mini HTTP stack myself), so how would a music streamer be different architecturally?  What libraries would I need to look at on the network side and on the MP3 side?

Comment: do you want things like VLC to be able to link into the stream, or would you just code your own client?

Comment: @thenoviceoof - great question, yes I would want "mainstream" clients to be able to connect.  iTunes, Winamp, VLC, etc.

Comment: Are you compressing the audio in real time or streaming pre-created MP3 files?

Comment: @rakslice - I'm just interested in streaming pre-created, compressed audio.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The mp3 format was designed for streaming, which makes some things simpler than you might have expected. The data is essentially a stream of [audio frames](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) with built-in boundary markers, rather than a file header followed by raw data. This means that once a client is expecting to receive audio data, you can just start sending it bytes from any point in an existing mp3 source, whether it be live or a file, and the client will sync up to the next frame it finds and start playing audio. Yay!

Of course, you'll have to give clients a way to set up the connection. The de-facto standard is the SHOUTcast (ICY) protocol. This is very much like HTTP, but with status and header fields just different enough that it isn't directly compatible with Python's built-in http server libraries. You might be able to get those libraries to do some of the work for you, but their documented interfaces won't be enough to get it done; you'll have to read their code to understand how to make them speak SHOUTcast.

Here are a few links to get you started:

https://web.archive.org/web/20220912105447/http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=70403

https://web.archive.org/web/20170714033851/https://www.radiotoolbox.com/community/forums/viewtopic.php?t=74

https://web.archive.org/web/20190214132820/http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoutcast

I suggest starting with a single mp3 file as your data source, getting the client-server connection setup and playback working, and then moving on to issues like live sources, multiple encoding bit rates, inband meta-data, and playlists.

Playlists are generally either .pls or .m3u files, and essentially just static text files pointing at the URL for your live stream. They're not difficult and not even strictly necessary, since many (most?) mp3 streaming clients will accept a live stream URL with no playlist at all.

As for architecture, the field is pretty much wide open. You have as many options as there are for HTTP servers. Threaded? Worker processes? Event driven? It's up to you. To me, the more interesting question is how to share the data from a single input stream (the broadcaster) with the network handlers serving multiple output streams (the players). In order to avoid IPC and synchronization complications, I would probably start with a single-threaded event-driven design. In python 2, a library like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) will give you [very good I/O performance](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) while allowing you to structure your code in a very understandable way.  In python 3, I would prefer asyncio coroutines.

Comment: would streaming dynamically generated .mp3 data require advanced python programming?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have good python experience (given you've already written an HTTP server) I can only provide a few pointers on how to extend the ground-work you've already done:

- Prepare your server for **dealing with Request Headers** like: `Accept-Encoding`, `Range`, `TE (Transfer Encoding)`, etc. An MP3-over-HTTP player (i.e. VLC) is nothing but an mp3 player that knows how to "speak" HTTP and "seek" to different positions in the file.
- Use wireshark or tcpdump to **sniff actual HTTP requests done by VLC** when playing an mp3 over HTTP, so you know how what request headers you'll be receiving and implement them.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into serving [m3u](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) or [pls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29) files.  That should give you a file format that players understand well enough to hit your http server looking for mp3 files.

A minimal m3u file would just be a simple text file with one song url per line.  Assuming you've got  the following URLs available on your server:

```
/playlists/<playlist_name/playlist_id>
/songs/<song_name/song_id>
```

You'd serve a playlist from the url:

```
/playlists/myfirstplaylist
```

And the contents of the resource would be just:

```
/songs/1
/songs/mysong.mp3
```

A player (like Winamp) will be able to open the URL to the m3u file on your HTTP server and will then start streaming the first song on the playlist.  All you'll have to do to support this is serve the mp3 file just like you'd serve any other static content.

Depending on how many clients you want to support you may want to look into asynchronous IO using a library like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) to support tons of simultaneous streams.

Comment: This sounds similar to SHOUTcast (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHOUTcast) which I do like.  My question is: how do I make it work so that the "playlist" file is just a generic URL that points to "stream" rather than a specific mp3 file?  Even if the URL is "/somefile.mp3", I don't want to have to generate a playlist with **each song**.  Rather, I want it to be a continuous flow of songs/commercials, etc., just like a radio station.  In fact, that's a great example.  How do radio stations do this from their websites, where you can listen to their live broadcast there?

Comment: I'm assuming they just continue to write audio content onto the clients http connection.  There's no reason that you a given URL can't represent an infinite stream of data.  If you don't close the connection the client will keep listening so when you've finished streaming a song file just start writing your commercial to the socket, and then another song.  Can you share some code so we can take a look at your simple HTTP server and maybe speak more concretely about what you'd need to do?

Comment: This answer doesn't address "start listening to whatever is currently playing, much like a radio station".

Answer (score 0):

Study these before getting too far:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Specifically

http://edna.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Edna doesn't address "start listening to whatever is currently playing, much like a radio station".

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have a .m3u or .pls file that points at a static URI (e.g. http://example.com/now_playing.mp3) then give them mp3 data starting wherever you are in the song when they ask for that file. Probably there are a bunch of minor issues I'm glossing over here...However, at least as forest points out, you can just start streaming the mp3 data from any byte.

Comment: Actually, you pretty much **can** just start blasting mp3 data at a client as soon as the client asks for it. MP3 encoding does not use a file header.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You're right, it's interleaved header/data throughout the file. Doing that would miss any ID3 tags, though, and my main point is that you probably shouldn't just start at any byte position at all still, you'll have to start at one of the headers.

Comment: You absolutely should just start at any byte position at all. The format was designed for exactly that. The sync bits are present in each frame specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Okay, I changed the answer. Thanks

Comment: How would you be able to tell which frame is being requested? I would like to keep track of the frames played in an mp3 file.