# How to play an mp3 file through Python socket?

Tags: python, audio, tcp, mp3, file-transfer

I'm having some trouble with my project.
I need to send an mp3 file using the TCP python socket and receive it in order to play it on the client's device.

When I'm sending the mp3 file I think it's on bytes - so I'm having trouble playing it.
here is a link to my project: https://github.com/OfekHarel/HorizonMusic

This is how I send the mp3 file - I Read the bytes directly through the file and sending it through the socket.

**So my question will be how to send and receive the file in a way that I can play it with the mp3 format.**

*Thank you.

Ofek Harel - Head of software sub-team in FRC team 3339.*

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688573/writing-a-python-music-streamer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are struggling with the same question:
I managed to solve it with a simple recv and send it by the TCP socket.
I formed a protocol that contained the size of the message and that's it.